# Is there a way to determine how I just lost 300 reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

Yesterday I had a little over 1,500 reputation on SO.  Today I have a little over 1,200.  The reputation tab on my profile does not indicate any mass down voting of my questions or answers.  I haven't received any comments or responses in the last day or so.

Is there any other way to find why 300 point would just go missing?

Comment: That would have to be one very bad answer/question to get that many downvotes. haha.

Comment: Hmm, I just manually added up all the upvotes on your profile to make a rough rep calculation. I came with about 1500 points.

Comment: My next theory is that ~30 upvotes are on questions/answers that have since turned to CW, and your rep has then been recalculated.

Comment: Holy cow!  You just counted all my votes?  I've never done that before.

Comment: You only have 39 questions and 43 answers; it isn't *that* hard to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's almost certainly going to be due to a "high value" question or answer being either deleted or (more likely) migrated to SuperUser, ServerFault or Meta.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your [reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42620?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top), I don't see a recent drop (or a drop of any kind), so I suspect that you lost reputation due to a rep recalc. Downvotes, bounties, and (iirc) posts that were removed as "offensive" are present in the graph. Other things like association bonuses are not, but I still think that this is due to a recalc.

Since you lost a substantial amount of rep, can you identify a popular question or answer that's missing from your profile? Perhaps it's a highly-ranked answer whose questions has been migrated to another site?

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the envelope beside your account name or look at the reputation graph in your profile.

However, this might have been due to a rep recalc, and you won't find it at all.

Comment: Guess this must be the case.  As far as I can tell none of my questions or answers went up or down more than 1 or 2 votes in teh last few days.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a question or answer that got flagged as offensive, you would have lost 100 points. That post would also be deleted, so you wouldn't see it unless you have 10k+ rep points.

So You could have lost that many points if you had three posts flagged as offensive.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6570/what-could-be-the-reason-of-a-negative-reputation), for more details.

Comment: I thought you lost 100 points when something was removed as offensive...? *runs to check FAQ*

Comment: According to the unofficial FAQ (which may be out of date) you lose 100 points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135685/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work-in-stackoverflow/135687#135687

Comment: @Kyle Cronin: Yes, it's -100 for an offensive post. At least it was a couple of weeks ago when I last observed it happening.

Comment: Fixed the answer, and added a reference.