# Lost 301 reputation after a manual reputation recalc

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers, reputation-recalc

Poking around the site I found [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation)
from the accepted answer to this post : [The global reputation recalc of March 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010).

After looking at the pretty numbers and feeling curious, I pressed the <kbd>Trigger Reputation Recalc</kbd> button :

[image]

I lost 301 reputation as shown in the diagrams below -

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17036050/scr184.png

I remembered that [a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121534/172936) of mine had been deleted and that I once heard (from the [highest authority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14017/172936)) that a sharp decrease in reputation can be caused by post deletion.

Would the [rep-recalc algorithms](http://ragegenerator.com/images/ragebuilder-faces/Determined-Focused/fumanchu.jpg) only catch this deletion 4 days later and only after I initiated it?

[Slightly related](http://www.jonodoiron.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Sad-Unicorn_reduced.jpg)

---

**Update**

On the brighter side of life - a re-calc on Stack Overflow gave me an extra 8rep :P  There is justice in the world ;)

Comment: Rep recalcs are not performed automatically.  It happened when you initiated it.  Deletions do not immediately result in a reduction of rep, only once a recalc is performed.  Recalculations do not take into account deleted content/votes.

Comment: @AdamDavis Rep recalcs actually do happen, but it isn't as often.

Comment: So even the votes on the deleted post wouldn't get "taken off"?  I hardly believe that I had 300reps taken away from serial upvoting :/

Comment: @SimonSheehan I'd like to hear more about that.  I know mods can initiate them, and they occur in cases of voting abuse, sockpuppets, and account merges.  I haven't heard that the system performs them at other times, or on a regular basis of any sort, though.

Comment: @Lix The votes on the deleted post are effectively removed when the recalc occurs.  You had 23 upvotes and 2 downvotes, so when the post was deleted and you ran a recalc you lost 226 rep from that one post.  You lost the other rep from other deleted posts, most likely.

Comment: You are mistaken about who is the highest authority on SO... =)

Comment: @casperOne - Just trying to be a little more [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121722/172936) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct.

Some of your answer(s) were deleted and you lost about 30 upvotes. Reputation from deleted posts remain until your recalculate it or until global recalculation is being performed (last one was a long ago)

Comment: I see...  Boo-hoo it is then :P  Perhaps the free-hand red circle will help me start climbing back up...

Comment: @Lix - Bug reports are deleted when the bug is fixed - sometimes even before it's fixed. Do you remember questions you answered or have bookmarked any?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - I didn't get any reputation from posing or answering any bug reports.

Comment: @Lix it's related because I lost rep due to bug reports I posted, they got upvoted then deleted. :-/

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - Ohhh! I see.   No - the only post that was deleted had substantial upvotes and was dealing with a proposition for Jeff to disperse his rep to us after he leaves :P  It was just [randomly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) deleted ;)

Comment: @Lix too bad then! Well, you got +45 so far - 255 to go. :-) (The single rep was probably not related)

Comment: @Sha Dow sorry, but from when are bug reports being deleted? That's new for me

Comment: @Martin not all, but I do remember one major bug about missing avatars where ALL bug reports have been deleted instantly, including the first report. There is no written policy though.